# How to split one column data multiple columns report in salesforce

Tags: reporting

I have attribute : test,system,sfdc

in report firstcolumn(test),secondcolumn(system),Thirdcolumn(sfdc)

if it is possible please any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no practical way to split a column in a report directly. You could build some formula fields, but it quickly becomes impractical, as you have to hard-code the number of values you need, each one becoming more convoluted than the one before it.

It'd be far easier to split the data in an external tool designed for such tasks, such as Microsoft Excel, which can easily split a column into multiple columns in a matter of a few clicks.

Comment: I ahve dateandtime( text filed) :2016-10-12 07:17:46,2016-10-12 07:18:01,2016-10-12 07:18:16   three dates spilt to Reg,Reg1,Reg2

Comment: ex: Reg=2016-10-12 07:17:46,Reg1=2016-10-12 07:18:01, reg =2016-10-12 07:18:16 like

please help me

Comment: @sindhuja What's your use case for doing this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: dateandtime three dates are there but i want three dates split   regreg1,reg2(formulafiled)

Comment: ex  like  Reg=2016-10-12 07:17:46,Reg1=2016-10-12 07:18:01, reg =2016-10-12 07:18:16

Comment: How Can I extract separate First and Last Names from a text field containing Full Name?

Comment: ex:First Name:
LEFT(FirstLastName__c,FIND(" ", FirstLastName__c))
Last Name:
RIGHT(FirstLastName__c, LEN(FirstLastName__c) - FIND(" ", FirstLastName__c))

Comment: I ahve dateandtime( text filed) :2016-10-12 07:17:46,2016-10-12 07:18:01,2016-10-12 07:18:16  three dates is there how to spilt three dates using formula fileds Like  Reg=2016-10-12 07:17:46,Reg1=2016-10-12 07:18:01, reg =2016-10-12 07:18:16